# How to package/deploy udash application?

Tags: udash

I developed a http://udash.io/ application. How do you package the web application for deployment?

I tried the sbt native-packager plugin, but it seems resources are not picked up, e.g. the static web assets.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure custom Mapping.

For example: `mappings in Universal ++= directory("target/UdashStatic")`

More about mappings: http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#mappingshelper